# String reorder by integers

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

The aim is to have any strings with integers within to be reorder by these integers.

Let's say you have the following string:

```
re5 Forty1 cash2 Man3 Booker4
```

The aim is to have the string order by the integer contained within the string:

```
Forty1 cash2 Man3 Booker4 re5
```

I created this function:

```
def reorder(wordchain):
    from re import findall
    splitchain = wordchain.split()
    entier = findall('\d+',wordchain)
    chaineok = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(entier,splitchain)]
    chaineok.sort(reverse = False)
    chaineok1 = [b[1] for b in chaineok]
    chaineok2 = " ".join(chaineok1)
    return chaineok2
```

The function is fine, however, there are a few things I would like to improve:

- The number of variable; I would like to have less. What should I do?
- The number of lines; I feel there can be fewer lines and definitely fewer operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `sorted()` for sorting and give your function and variables better names.
Something like this:

```
import re

find_int = re.compile('(\d+)')


def reorder(sentence):
    def num_part(word):
        return int(find_int.search(word).group(0))

    return ' '.join(sorted(sentence.split(), key=num_part))
```

Comment: This answer does not provide any explanation. Why is your solution better than the OPs' ? Why did you choose to do it like this and not like OP did ?

Comment: Hi @user3637203, I'm not familiar with Lambda. Can you explain a bit,please?

Comment: @Dex'ter seems fine to me. He pointed out `sorted()`, and that names can be improved, and demonstrated how. He made other, unexplained improvements, but that doesn't make it a bad answer.

Comment: @janos I didn't say it's a bad answer but it lacks some explanations which would help the OP understand what he actually did there ^_^.

Comment: @Dex'ter you said it "does not provide any explanation". That's not true. I don't think the downvote is justified, and it's not a nice welcome for a new user.

Comment: It's nice you moved the `import` statement out of the function, it would be great if you could include an explanation why that's a good thing, and also a word about `lambda`, as the poster asked ;-)

Comment: I made a few changes: assigning a lambda to a variable is not recommended, using a `def` is better, and probably OP understands this better too. The original function returned a string, so I added a `join`. I also further improved the variables a bit. Hope you don't mind, feel free to change it.